# Issue to file a vector list

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using a vector of struct in order to create a kind of minimal filesystem. The entry point is a FileSystem struct manage by MTP but it contain to much data and it also force me to deploy mtp stuff even at high-level.

What I have done is to parse the list of files provided by MTP and file a vector of struct.

here is what I have in the cpp file

```
std::vector<FileObject*> mtp_wrapper::ListsOfFirstLevel(uint32_t idx) {

    std::vector<FileObject*> ListOfObjects;
    LIBMTP_file_t *AllFiles;
    LIBMTP_file_t *file;

    AllFiles = getListOfFiles();

    file = AllFiles;

    while(file !=NULL) {
        LIBMTP_file_t *oldfile;
        FSitem = new FileObject();

        if(file->parent_id == idx) {

            FSitem->filename = file->filename;

            FSitem->filesize = file->filesize;
            if(file->filetype == LIBMTP_FILETYPE_FOLDER)
                FSitem->isFolder = true;
            else
                FSitem->isFolder = false;

            FSitem->itemid = file->item_id;
            FSitem->parent_id = file->parent_id;
            FSitem->lastmodified = file->modificationdate;
            ListOfObjects.push_back(FSitem);
           // free(FSitem)
        }
        oldfile = file;
        file = file->next;
        LIBMTP_destroy_file_t(oldfile);
    }
    return ListOfObjects;
}
```

FileObject is declared in a header file as below

```
struct FileObject {
    uint32_t itemid;
    bool isFolder;
    char *filename;
    uint64_t filesize;
    LIBMTP_filetype_t filetype;
    uint32_t location;
    uint32_t parent_id;
    time_t lastmodified;
};
```

The code to file the FSitem is working fine, FSItem is file correctly but at the end of while, the ListOfOjects is empty. seems like the push_back fail...

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger, line by line, to see what happens. Maybe the condition `file->parent_id == idx` is never true?

Comment: you have a leak when `parent_id == idx` is false. you dont need to use pointers, a `vector<FileObject>` is enough.

Comment: Also, remember that for the `filename` member you are copying a *pointer*, if this pointer is released somewhere (like in e.g. `LIBMTP_destroy_file_t`) then you have a stray pointer. Also, since you have a linked list, should you really call the `LIBMTP_destroy_file_t` on each node in the list, instead on the whole list?

Comment: [offtopic] you really shouldn't capitalise variable names. It's just a convention, but everyone follows it and it helps readability. Captitalize Type names. Even the syntaxic parser on stackoverflow assume that everything that starts with a capital letter is a typename.

Answer (score 0):

```
       ListOfObjects.push_back(FSitem);
       // free(FSitem)
```

Why do you free FSItem ? You have a std::vector of pointers. When you call push_back you copy the pointer to your item inside the vector. The item hasn't moved and hasn't been copied. If you free `FSItem` , you delete the object, and then the pointer in your vector will be invalid.

Comment: I do not free it. it's commented.